# Issue Populating Filter Value for AG Grid agSetColumnFilter

Tags: ag-grid

I'm trying to populate the value for the agSetColumnFilter, but I'm getting an error that I cannot find anything where in documentation (or anywhere online). Has anyone ever run into this issue?

This is what the column definition looks like:

```
columnDefs.push({
                headerName: col.name,
                field: col.name,
                def: col,
                rowGroup: k < groupedColumnCount ? true : false,
                pinned: k < _this.groupBy.length ? 'left' : null,
                lockPinned: k < _this.groupBy.length ? true : false,
                hide: k < groupedColumnCount ? true : false,
                suppressToolPanel: _this.groupBy.length ? true : false,
                valueGetter: function(data){
                    if(data.data){
                        var def = data.colDef.def;
                        var value = data.data[data.colDef.field];
                        if(value){
                            return value.value;
                        }else{
                            return null;
                        }
                    }else{
                        return data.value;
                    }
                },
                valueFormatter: function(data){
                    if(data.data){
                        var def = data.colDef.def;
                        var value = data.data[data.colDef.field];
                        if(!value) return null;

                        if(value.formatted){
                            _this.cache[data.colDef.field + value.value] = value.formatted;    
                        }

                        return value.formatted ? value.formatted : value.value;
                    }else{
                        if(_this.cache[data.colDef.field + data.value]){
                            return _this.cache[data.colDef.field + data.value];
                        }else{
                            return data.value;
                        }
                    }
                },
                keyCreator: function(params){
                    console.log(params);
                },
                filter: 'agSetColumnFilter', 
                filterParams: {
                    values: function (params) {
                        params.success([{
                            $uri: 'nhuihi',
                            value: {
                                $value: 'some text'
                            }
                        }]);
                    }
                }
            });
```

I'm only printing out keyCreator params for now since I don't know what will actually be available in the data. The idea is that I can set values using complex objects returned from the server and display a formatted value instead of a key. This is the error I'm getting.

```
ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js:formatted:27684 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onFilterValuesReady' of undefined
    at t.setFilterValues (ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js:formatted:27684)
    at e.modelUpdatedFunc (ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js:formatted:27609)
    at e.onAsyncValuesLoaded (ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js:formatted:27917)
    at values (comparison-table-v7.js:1253)
    at e.createAllUniqueValues (ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js:formatted:27909)
    at new e (ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js:formatted:27867)
    at t.initialiseFilterBodyUi (ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js:formatted:27608)
    at t.init (ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js:formatted:18945)
    at e.initialiseComponent (ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js:formatted:10602)
    at e.createAgGridComponent (ag-grid-enterprise.min.noStyle.js:formatted:10574)
```

Here's a test case for it as well. I simply modified the example by AG Grid. https://plnkr.co/edit/GURQHP0KKFpJ9kwaU83M?p=preview

If you open up console, you will see an error when you click on Athletes filter.

Also reported on GitHub: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2829

Answer (score 0):

If you need to configure filter values without async requests

```
filterParams: {
    values: getFilterValuesData()
}

getFilterValuesData(){
    //data preparation 
    //little bit modified sample to present that you can handle your logic here
    let data = [];
    [
        'John Joe Nevin',
        'Katie Taylor',
        'Paddy Barnes',
        'Kenny Egan',
        'Darren Sutherland',
        'Margaret Thatcher',
        'Tony Blair',
        'Ronald Regan',
        'Barack Obama'
    ].forEach(i=>{
        data.push(i);
    });
        return data;
    }
```

If it requires to make an async request for data preparation you can use `callback` function:

```
filterParams: {
    values: (params)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{  -- setTimeout on this case only for async request imitation
            params.success(['value 1', 'value 2'])
        }, 5000)
    }
}
```

> **Notice**: `params.success(...)` should be used only with an async request
>
> Doc: <kbd>[ag-grid Asynchronous Values](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-set/#asynchronous-values)</kbd>

Comment: This is clearly a bug and they are looking into it now. I did try setting timeout to 1ms and it worked which means that variable is not set until after the function is invoked. This workaround may work now, but it could be problematic later. Anyway, will update again once the team gets back to me.